# Google Docs: converting distance units

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I'm trying to have a function for a Google Docs Document that will search the whole text for a number followed by the abbreviation "km.", pass the value of this number to a variable and multiply it, and replace the original text with the new variable plus "mi."

Basically, if there's some part in the text that reads "10km.", I'd need it to convert to "6.2mi."

So far I have this:

```
function replaceKmToMi(){
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var kilometers = body.findText("\\d+" + "km.");
var km = parseInt(kilometers);
var mi = km / 1.609;
var miles = mi + "mi."
body.replaceText(kilometers, miles);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?